# Increase Font Size of Chart Title in Altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I can't figure out how to increase the size of the font for the chart title in Altair. My code will only change the font size for the axis titles, but not for the chart title.

Here's what I tested out:

```
data = df
bars = alt.Chart(data, title="This is the Chart Title").mark_bar().encode(
    x = 'Feature1',
    y = 'Feature2',
    color = alt.Color('Feature1', legend=None)).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=16,
    titleFontSize=16
)

bars
```

In this instance, the `titleFontSize` argument changes the font for the axis titles (`'Feature1'` and `'Feature2'` in this example). Is there any easy way to increase the font for the chart title?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you call `configure_axis`, you are only configuring properties related to the axis. If you want to configure the properties of the chart title, you can use `configure_title()`; e.g.

```
bars.configure_title(fontSize=24)
```